# Can I retrieve 2 different results from 1 table in a single query?

Tags: mysql

I am making a pagination function, here is my case:

1 table (example)

```
id | title | date | details
```

Now, I want to retrieve two different results from this table (example)

1. Count all of the rows (for the total count of all the lists)
2. I will only show every 10 list per page.

My current code is, I have 2 separated queries for `1` and `2`, so it is like 2 connections, my question is, can this be done with a single query and then retrieve both of `1` and `2` results? If so, what do I need to do? Any suggestion/s can help me!

Comment: ANswer is __No you can't__

Comment: Please check this out for "out of the ordinary" ways to optimize pagination - http://www.xarg.org/2011/10/optimized-pagination-using-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

I think,

This will help you.

Step 1: Get the all list from the table
Step 2: Then count the records

Here is the single query to perform it.

```
SELECT COUNT(tmp.id) as cnt, tmp.* FROM (SELECT id, title, date, details FROM tablename) tmp
```